# Flash/AS3 Refuses to Import

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, import

No matter what I've tried, this code refuses to compile. I constantly get this compile error. I'm trying to make a volume slider in my flash animation. As far as I can tell I'm importing all the right things, and my code is exactly the same as numerous examples I've looked it. Why does this not work?

```
    Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 50 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SliderEvent.
```

```
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import fl.controls.Slider; 
    import fl.events.SliderEvent; 

    var curSound = 0;
    var lastSound = 0;

    var _A1:Sound = new A1();
    var _A2:Sound = new A2();
    var _A3:Sound = new A3();
    var _A4:Sound = new A4();
    var _A5:Sound = new A5();
    var _A6:Sound = new A6();
    var _A7:Sound = new A7();
    var _A8:Sound = new A8();
    var _A9:Sound = new A9();
    var _A10:Sound = new A10();
    var _A11:Sound = new A11();
    var _A12:Sound = new A12();

    var voiceVolume:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    voiceVolume.volume = .4;

    var voiceChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    var volSlider:Slider = new Slider();
    volSlider.minimum = 0;
    volSlider.maximum = 1;
    volSlider.value = .5;
    volSlider.snapInterval = .1;
    volSlider.liveDragging = true;
    volSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, volChange);
    volSlider.move(10, 10);
    addChild(slider);

    function volChange(ev:SliderEvent):void{
        voiceVolume.volume = ev.value;
        voiceChannel.soundTransform = voiceVolume;
    }
```

EDIT: In fact, if I comment the offending line out, it can't find anything I'm trying to import. What the heck?

```
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 2   1172: Definition fl.controls:Slider could not be found.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 3   1172: Definition fl.events:SliderEvent could not be found.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 2   1172: Definition fl.controls:Slider could not be found.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 3   1172: Definition fl.events:SliderEvent could not be found.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 26  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Slider.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 26  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Slider.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 32  1120: Access of undefined property SliderEvent.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 32  1120: Access of undefined property volChange.
Preloader, Layer 'Sounds AS', Frame 1, Line 34  1120: Access of undefined property slider.
```

Comment: Are you compiling with FlashDevelop?

Comment: Nope, within the Flash CS6 Actionscript editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Flash components (`fl.*`) you are required to drop the component into the Library panel of Flash Professional.  Doing so creates a linkage to the specific component you want to use.

Once you drag a `Slider` component from the `Components` panel and drop it into the `Library` you will be able to compile without error.

[image]

Comment: Stupid restriction IMHO, but nice to know. Thanks.